# Is it possible to edit a table via dblink in APEX?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, dblink

I've created a form in the APEX and I need to edit a table via `dblink`, which is already created . So, when I ask to show me a data in this remoute  table- it's work fine, but when I'm trying to edit data, I get the  error:

> "Table or view OPERATION@DBQA not found Contact your application
>   administrator."

In the `SQL workshop>SQL Commands`- it also works fine(

```
update usr.operation@dbqa
set description='admin3' where operation_id=10
```

)

Well, I've created view `usr.operation_qa as select * from usr.operation@dbqa`, but, anyway, I receive the same error

> "Table or view OPERATION_QA not found Contact your application
>   administrator."

I'll repeat, a `permission` and `dblink` -are ok, couse it's worl in `SQL Commands`

Will be appreciate for any help or comments. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure - I haven't made an Apex app that updates a table across a dblink directly before. Instead of a view, have you tried using a synonym instead, e.g. `CREATE SYNONYM operation FOR usr.operation@dbqa;`? It's possible you may need to substitute a custom PL/SQL process to replace the default DML process that Apex generates.

Comment: Hi! 
Yes, i've tried to create a synonym also, but it didb't help=(

But I've found an another solution- i've created a page PL/SQL  process after submit, where  update my view usr.operation_qa just directly by pl/sql block like
"update usr.operation_qa
set description=:P...
where operation_id=:P.."

Comment: Very good - that's what I meant by PL/SQL process. If you submit your comment as an answer you can accept it.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp, actually, you have really answered on my question-i've just not realized it at once,thank you!
 so if you will repeat iy in answer- i will accept it with pleasure!
because I can't submit a comment